# Can I speak to my companion in the cantina in the Sith academy on Korriban?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've heard that when your companion needs to speak to you on SWTOR KotFE, you need to go to a cantina or your ship. I'm a Sith, so would the cantina on Korriban do?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a cantina is a cantina.  It should say that you entered a rest area when you go in; if not, you've mistaken some other place for a cantina.

However, some conversations specifically require that you use your ship (after you acquire it).  Those will be indicated by a small ship icon on your companion's portrait.